# error: java.lang.NullPointerException: toolbar must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I am using a navigation drawer .My app was working fine before that but after the code of navigation from drawer to fragment , it is showing this error! Should i change something in style?

```
  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
```

this is my fragment code i.e. when i will click on the drawer item i will be navigated to this fragment.

Comment: Your **toolbar** is referring to **null** . Make sure you have initialized it properly

Comment: i think so its correct..what to do next?

Comment: Initialize it with the correct **toolbar** id with of your **xml** file..